# How to rename values of JSON data if they meet certain parameters?

Tags: ios, swift

I have TableView inside a ViewController that is populated using JSON data:

If for example, the JSON data contains a `status` for some records called **"Processed"** and another called **"In Progress"**

Can the sections which are based on the status say **"Ready"** and **"Not Ready"** instead when displayed as sections?

Comment: You want to display the message like "Ready" and "Not Ready" on tableView header in each section? That's what you are trying to say.

Comment: Correct, if the `status` from JSON says  "Processed" the section header should say Ready - If the `status` says "In Progress" the section header should say "Not Ready"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in the comment if status from JSON says "Processed" then Ready otherwise Not Ready. Following the same logic, you could do something similar

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let model = sections[section]
        if model.status == "Processed"{
            return "Ready"
        }else{
            return "Not Ready"
        }
    }
```